# Construct a while loop around a command throwing a segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault

I have a program that throws a segmentation fault on certain circumstances.  I want to execute a command when the segmentation fault occurs to process the data, then execute the command again, and keep doing so until the segmentation fault stops.

As a rough attempt at pseudo code,

```
dodgy_command

while SegFault
         dataProcessing
         dodgy_command
end
```

I think I need to be using a Trap command, but I don't understand the syntax for this command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a program aborts abnormally the exit code (as seen by the shell) typically has the high bit set so the value is 128 or higher.  So a simple solution might be

```
dodgy_command

while [ $? -ge 128 ]
do
  process_data
  dodgy_command
done
```

If you specifically only want a segfault and not any other type of error, the while line becomes `$? -eq 139` (because SEGV is signal 11; 128+11=139).

If you don't get an high valued exit code on failure then it probably means the application is trapping the error, itself, and forcing a different exit code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what language you need to do this in.  So, I'm assuming shell script.

You are correct, you want to use a trap.  The trap in bash takes a string to execute when a signal is received.  I tend to make it a function call so I can clearly define what I want done when I trap the signal.

Here is a sample script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# define the function that will handle the trap
sigSegFault() { echo "Inside sigSegFault"; }

# Trap the Segmentation Violation (signal 11) signal
trap sigSegFault SEGV

# Start infinite loop    
while [[ true ]]; do
  sleep 10
done

exit 0
```

Simplistic, but contains the basics of what you are asking for.